# Nested generic wildcard binding in ninject

Tags: c#, generics, ninject, ninject-2

Is there a clean way to bind to a nested generic "wildcard" in Ninject?

I know that I can ask for any arbitrary `IThing<T>` with the following binding:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IThing<>)).To(typeof(Thing<>));
```

However, what I really want is any arbitrary `IThing<Foo<T>>`. The following does not work syntactically:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IThing<Foo<>>)).To(typeof(FooThing<>));
```

This works syntactically:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IThing<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Foo<>))).To(typeof(FooThing<>));
```

But ninject doesn't know what to do with that. Can Ninject achieve this sort of thing?

Comment: Would you be able to define an interface like `public interface IFooThing<T> : IThing<Foo<T>>`? because then you would be able to bind as usual `kernel.Bind(typeof(IFooThing<>)).To(typeof(FooThing<>));`

Comment: Yes, that's certainly an option, but I'm not really a fan of the "marker interface" kind of thing since it doesn't provide any real meaning to the program. I would rather my code dictate the dependency injection binding than the other way around.

Comment: If you're curious, the use case is that IThing<T> is actually IParser<T>. I want to have composable XML parsers. For instance, I have a document that parses into Foo<T> with a node that can be parsed to any format, so sometimes T is Bar, and sometimes it's Bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: no, you cannot do this with Ninject. In fact, the only DI library that actually supports this kind of complex bindings using partially closed generic types is Simple Injector. In Simple Injector you can do this:

```cs
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IThing<>),
    typeof(Thing<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Foo<>)));
```

And in your example you have a `FooThing<T>` that probably contains a nested type constraint as follows:

```cs
public class FooThing<T> : IThing<Foo<T> { }
```

Again, Ninject does not support this. I believe that Autofac has some support for this up to some level, but only Simple Injector is able to resolve types for your with almost any bizarre and complex generic type constraints. In Simple Injector that registration is simply:

```cs
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IThing<>), typeof(FooThing<>));
```

And Simple Injector will find out for you that it has to resolve a `FooThing<int>` when an `IThing<Foo<int>>` is requested.

Comment: Informative post, thanks. I'm not sure that either of those registrations do what I want though. Would the second one allow me to register more IThing<Bar> instances?

Comment: Hi @Hans. In fact, none of the given registrations do what you want, because they are examples of Simple Injector, not Ninject :-). Compared to other DI libraries, Simple Injector makes [a clear separation between 'normal' registrations and registrations of collections](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decisions.html#separate-collections). If you like to know how to do things with Simple Injector, best is to ask a new question here at Stackoverflow.

Comment: Right I understand that. I don't really care so much about ninject, that just happens to be what I'm using right now. The nice thing about DI done right is it's fairly simple to replace the framework.

Comment: @Hans, exactly! DI is about applying the patterns and principles; the tools come after that.

Comment: But here's a little teaser about Simple Injector. If you have a collection of (open) generic types, you can register them in Simple Injector as follows: `container.RegisterAll(typeof(IThing<>), new[] { typeof(Thing<>), typeof(FooThing<>), typeof(NonGenericThing), typeof(etc) })`. You can resolve them by calling `container.GetAllInstances<IThing<Something>>()` or have a collection argument in a constructor (such as `IEnumerable<T>`).